# How do I add dynamic value to aria-labelledby in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, haml

I am very new to ruby. I want to append dynamic value to `aria-labelledby` to some unordered list.

Here is my code:

`%ul.tags{aria: {labelledby: '#{title}'} }= render partial:'questions/question'`

Here title is attribute which will change dynamically. So I wanted to append dynamic values to id and this worked very well .

`%h3{:id => "#{title}"}`

But the same thing not working for aria-labelledby.

Comment: did you try using `"#{title}"` i.e., in double quotes?

Comment: Just use `render 'questions/question'`. There is no reason to use `partial:`. Also, you can just use `id: title` and `labelledby: title`, you don't need the `"#{}"` wrapper.

Comment: I tried with title but its rendering as labelledby="title"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `'` instead of `"`.

```
%ul.tags{"aria-labelledby" => "#{title}" }= render partial:'questions/question'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I tried single quote too there is no error but in my html I am getting this as output <ul aria-labelledby="#{title}" class="tags"> which is wrong.

Comment: I tried this its giving me error like this:                                                          wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..3)